# Swimlanes in GitHub Projects

Tags: github, github-projects

I'm moving from Jira to GitHub Projects to visualise our work. Our team works on multiple products at the same time. Does anyone know if GitHub-Projects allows the concept of swimlanes (like in Jira) so that similar issues can be grouped together across the different states?

Answer (score 3):

Swimlanes are not currently a feature of Github Projects.

Answer (score 0):

They are a feature now! You can have a status column with multiple values such as To Do, In Progress, In Review, and Done.